# Enum equality (and EventHandlerList's keys)

Tags: c#, events

## Subtitle: Can EventHandlerList key's Type be something else than object?

I wanted to use an enum store the keys I would like to have in an EventHandler.

```
public enum EventKey
{
    OnBark, OnCry
}

public EventHandlerList EventList = new EventHandlerList();

public event ComplaintEventHandler OnBark
{
    add
    {
        EventList.AddHandler(EventKey.OnBark, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        EventList.RemoveHandler(EventKey.OnBark, value);
    }
}

var handler = EventList[eventKey] as ComplaintEventHandler;
```

>

```
handler = null
```

As it turns out it does not work. But it works if I use keys declared like ([as shown on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8843a9ch)):

```
static object EventKeyOnTap = new object();
```

After reading some mscorlib's code I see that the problem comes from `next.key == key` in

```
private EventHandlerList.ListEntry Find(object key)
{
    EventHandlerList.ListEntry next = this.head;

    while (next != null && next.key != key)
    {
        next = next.next;
    }
    return next;
}
```

Both compared keys are from my `Enum`, but they are not equal!
I guess it comes from some implicit casts to `object` happening (the key stored in the list is of type `object`) but am not fluent enough with such low-level concepts.

Is my guess right?

### What is the best way to use an `Enum` as a key in an `EventHandlerList`?

<strike>For now I will create my own `EventHandlerList` with `Enum` as key Type.</strike>

For now I created my own `EventHandlerList` with a constructor taking a `Func<object, object, bool>` which I then use in place of the equality comparaison aforementioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. Can you explain output?

```
var bark1 = (object)EventKey.OnBark;
var bark2 = (object)EventKey.OnBark;

Console.WriteLine(bark1 != bark2);
Console.WriteLine(bark1.Equals(bark2));
```

If yes, I don't know why you asked this question. If no, you definitely should get aware of **value types**, **reference types** and **boxing**.

In short, `AddHandler` method accepts `object` parameter, hence your key (which is value type) is boxed when you call:

```
EventList.AddHandler(EventKey.OnBark, value);
```

If you call this method twice with the same enum key, key will be boxed twice, and two different objects in heap will be actually created.

That's why this check `next.key != key` inside `Find` method fails (it compares addresses of two separate objects in heap).

EventHandlerList is sealed class, so you cannot affect its guts, but in your own code you could handle this situation with better check:

```
next.key.Equals(key)
```

Comment: Thank you alex. As I said I am not fluent with these concepts of boxing even though I know a bit. That explanation help me getting a better grasp on it.